# My game custom input adapter is not running rendering system

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, entity-component-system

I am using Ashley and Guicer to make ECS game with LibGDX and Kotlin. Everything works fine except that when i click, entity spawns without texture. When i am calling addEntity in the main file the texture is loaded but in **MyInputAdapter** texture just doesn't load.

Here is **MyInputAdapter** class:

```
class MyInputAdapter @Inject constructor(private val camera: OrthographicCamera,
                                     private val engine: Engine,
                                     private val world: World) :
    InputAdapter() {
override fun touchDown(screenX: Int, screenY: Int, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
    val worldCords = camera.unproject(Vector3(screenX.toFloat(), screenY.toFloat(), 0f))

    engine.addEntity(Entity().apply {
        add(TextureRegionComponent(TextureRegion(Main.img)))
        add(TransformComponent(Vector2(worldCords.x, worldCords.y), 50f, 0.2f))

        val body = world.createBody(BodyDef().apply {
            type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody
        })
        body.createFixture(PolygonShape().apply {
            setAsBox(1f, 1f)
        }, 1.0f)
        body.setTransform(transform.position, 0f)
        add(PhysicsComponent(body))
    })

    return true
  }
}
```

And here is registration of the adapter in **Main** class:

```
 override fun create() {
    batch = SpriteBatch()
    img = Texture("badlogic.jpg")
    injector = Guice.createInjector(GameModule(this))
    injector.getInstance(Systems::class.java).list.map { injector.getInstance(it) }.forEach { system ->
        engine.addSystem(system)
    }

    createEntities()

    Gdx.input.inputProcessor = injector.getInstance(MyInputAdapter::class.java)
}
```

The **TextureRegionComponent** is ignored in input adapter, but it's not in **Main** class:

```
private fun createEntities() {
    val world = injector.getInstance(World::class.java)
    engine.addEntity(Entity().apply {
        add(TextureRegionComponent(TextureRegion(img)))
        add(TransformComponent(Vector2(5F, 5F)))

        val body = world.createBody(BodyDef().apply {
            type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody
        })
        body.createFixture(PolygonShape().apply {
            setAsBox(img.width.pixelToMeter / 2f, img.height.pixelToMeter / 2f)
        }, 1.0f)
        body.setTransform(transform.position, 0f)
        add(PhysicsComponent(body))
    })
    ...
}
```

Here is some picture:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXkRE.png)

Comment: In your two examples, you're using different TransformComponent constructors. Can you show your TransformComponent class? I'm wondering if your region is getting drawn off-screen.

Comment: ```//Transform component

class TransformComponent(val position: Vector2, var angleRadian: Float, var scale: Float) : Component {
    constructor(position: Vector2) : this(position, 0f, 1f)

    companion object : ComponentResolver<TransformComponent>(TransformComponent::class.java)
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

So I figured it out now. Problem was that i didn't set binder correctly in my **GameModule** class

```
class GameModule(private val main: Main) : Module {
  override fun configure(binder: Binder) {
    binder.requireAtInjectOnConstructors() //<-- this was missing
    binder.requireExactBindingAnnotations() //<-- and this too
    binder.bind(SpriteBatch::class.java).toInstance(main.batch)
  }
  ...
}
```